# Deadlock in Queue table when using multi-threading

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple queue table and several threads that enqueue and dequeue messages from the queue table. Using SQL Server 2012.

I'm getting deadlocked during the dequeue SQL below. Can someone give me a hint what the issue may be and how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Error:

> Transaction (Process ID 96) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Code:

```
// ENQUEUE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SendSequenceId bigint;
    SET @SendSequenceId = NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[SEQ_SEND_MESSAGE_QUEUE_ID]

    UPDATE TOP (1) [dbo].[MESSAGE_QUEUE] WITH (ROWLOCK)
    SET [MessageId] = @SendSequenceId,
        [IsUsed] = 1
    WHERE IsUsed = 0
END             

// DEQUEUE
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (1) [dbo].[MESSAGE_QUEUE] WITH (ROWLOCK)
    SET 
        @MessageOut = [Message],
        [IsUsed] = 0,
        [MessageId] = NULL,
        [Status] = 0,
        [Message] = ''
    WHERE IsUsed = 1
END
```

Comment: What is your isolation level? `SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified' 
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted' 
WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable' 
WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable' 
WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where session_id = @@SPID`

Comment: Hello. For the locked processes it says 'ReadCommitted'

Comment: How reliable is the error?  Every time?  Most of the time?  Just occasionally?  Have you been able to identify what SPID was the "other side" of the deadlock?

Comment: It happens every time when using a larger number of concurrent processes - like 100. Also noticed that it happens during enqueue when I don't even use the dequeue processes.

Comment: Set your isolation level as `SERIALIZABLE` for the queue/dequeue procedures.

Comment: Isplation level SERIALIZABLE as they wrote, or if you really use top 1 - REPITABLE READ